# How can I expand my office network with a SG300-28P switch?

Tags: switch, switching, stacking, cisco-sg300

At this moment, I have a SG300-28P switch, but it's running out of ports. I want to order another SG300-28p, but I have no idea what modules and cables I need to stack those switches.

Does anyone know this?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No much information in your question how you currently have the switch configured L2/L3 or both, but a quick answer is you aren't really stacking this model as it's not a stackable model. (stackables have only one IP address to manage the stack) You can daisy chain them together using one of the four ports on the front right side and configure as a trunk port on the existing and new switch. Can be technically done with any port but suggest one of the four. Or you can use one of the open SFP slots and buy two fiber modules.

Part number# MGBSX1 "1000BASE-SX SFP transceiver, for multimode fiber, 850 nm wavelength" and a 50 micron fiber patch cord between switches. Assuming in the same rack located together a 1-3 meter cable will do.

On most Cisco models if you use one of the SFP ports the the associated copper port is not usable.

All of the ports on the down stream switch are sharing the one uplink to the up stream switch. If this is a small office with mostly internet and low bandwidth traffic then this isn't a problem.

Again the ports are either configured as defaults and the two connecting ports between the switches will auto negotiate a link. But if an engineer has made changes to the default config then the link might not come up and spanning tree will shutdown the port.

Best to find a local network engineer that works with Cisco products and consult with them for the greatest success.

Comment: Hey as long as I can download with 80MB per second from the server on switchA to my client on switchB, im good. Is this possible with the 1000BASE-SX SFP transceiver and the fiber patch cord? I actually want to make 1 big switch of those 2 switches. thanks in advance!

Comment: 80mb is no problem. Can have multiple users at 80mb at the same time. You don't have to buy the fiber parts per se. In a small office using one of the copper 1gb ports as the trunk link is quite ok. I've used copper trunks many times daisy chaining switches together for smaller port count needs. If you have already used up all 28 ports as long as you can move one of the users/devices down to the second switch to free up a port on the existing switch that will work. All depends on config. Suggest sourcing a local engineer for second opinion.

Comment: So, if im correct, I only have to buy a xx cable and put it in the GBIC ports of the switches??

Comment: If you look at the front of the switch on the right there is a group of 4 copper ports. You have two options. use one of those with a standard Cat 5e or Cat 6 patch cord and make the switch to switch connection or buy the fiber module and fiber patch cord. Caveat if the fiber port is used it will disable one of the associated copper ports in that four port grouping. Example for copper pick port 28 on each switch and connect together. Again the config on the existing switch matters if different than the defaults. Don't if the existing switch was taken out of box & installed unconfigured or not.

Comment: but the 24 other ports are all Gbit ports, so if a few clients download something of the server on the other switch, its on its max, right?

Comment: the connection between the two switches is 1gb. One user downloading at 1gb rate or 10 users @ 80mb=800mb. Again you are daisychaining switches together not making one big switch. This product line does not support Cisco Stackwise stacking which makes one big switch out of many. For a small office chaining together should be fine. The downstream switch is throttled at a max of 1gb total throughput. The existing switch users are not technically limited but most servers for small offices are 1gb NIC's so probably still not an issue. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: One last comment on the subject. If you truly want this to be one big switch as you described then replace the existing 300-28P with a 300-52P model. That will keep everything in one switch. The -28P could be chained off of the new switch later on if you need more than 52 ports.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some doubt about your bandwidth, you can configure between the 2 switchs an etherchannel, on the way to take a link with more capacity between A and B. If you dont know what it is an etherchannel, it´s a configuration that permit bound a few interfaces to make on logical interface. If you bound 2 Gigabit interfaces on the 2 swithces, you can create a link of 2 Gigabit between then, and so on.

Etherchannel will provides you more bandwidth, load-balance and redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

You just buy another one and plug it in to the existing one with a Cat5/6 cable (or two for redundancy via an etherchannel).  If they are far apart, get the miniGBIC for multimode fiber x2 (one for each switch, or x4 2 for each) and plug it in that way.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/sg300-28p-28-port-gigabit-poe-managed-switch/model.html

The Cisco 300 Series also offers mini gigabit interface converter (mini-GBIC) expansion slots that give you the option to add fiber-optic or Gigabit Ethernet uplink connectivity to the switch.